# NAs in a column that doesn't contain NAs R

Tags: r, dplyr, na, missing-data

I'm trying to understand what is happening to my code. Suppose I have data from [this Google Forms](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfSr-FEutluNVt5Ll3faR0QiIhh4-PUftBDB3HC0eChBF7gsQ/viewform?usp=sf_link) and I want to calculate the percentages of a question with multiple options (namely, *STRATEGY*). There are no Nas in *STRATEGY*, but when I use `select(select(ID, SCHOOL, STRATEGY)` it gives me a bunch of Nas. Why is that happening?

Suppose this is a survey on 5 different types of schools (SCHOOL) and we want to know how each type of school deals with learning strategies (STRATEGY).

- My code:
- Part 1: extract values [separed by commas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74139754/how-to-split-values-separated-by-commas-in-the-same-row-to-different-rows-in-r):

```
### convert Q3:

colnames(df) <- c('ID', 'ORIGIN', 'SCHOOL', 'STRATEGY', 'PREFERENCE', 'STRENGH', 'WEAKNESS')

### try to slipt:

df1 <-  df %>% 
  pivot_longer(c(STRATEGY, STRENGH, WEAKNESS)) %>%
  separate_rows(value, sep = ",") %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider() %>%
  select(-row) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(-ID), na_if,"")  ### change them all into NA mutate_all(na_if,"") %>%
```

- Part 2: Check learning strategies by school type:

```
## SELECT:
 
 test2 <- df1 %>% select(ID, SCHOOL, STRATEGY) %>% 
          # filter(!is.na(SCHOOL)) %>% 
         group_by(SCHOOL)
 
 ## see
 
 test2[10:15,]
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   SCHOOL [2]
  ID       SCHOOL        STRATEGY                 
  <chr>    <chr>         <chr>                    
1 PERSON_2 School type C " watching Netflix"      
2 PERSON_2 School type C  NA                      
3 PERSON_2 School type C  NA                      
4 PERSON_2 School type C  NA                      
5 PERSON_3 School type D "social media (Instagram"
6 PERSON_3 School type D " Twitter"
```

- Nas:

```
> sum(is.na(df$STRATEGY))
[1] 0
> 
> sum(is.na(df1$STRATEGY))
[1] 81
```

I've seen similar questions ([ex1](https://community.rstudio.com/t/dropping-missing-values-while-using-dplyr-group-by-summarise-n/126742/2) [ex2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29501188/dplyr-removing-nas-from-group-by-variable)), they recommend that we filter NAs from the `group_by` column, but I don't have any NAs in `SCHOOL`.

- **Question**: I have NAs on the `STRENGH` and `WEAKNESS` columns, but not in `STRATEGY`. **Why are they showing up, then?**
- Notes:
- 1. I don't want to exclude `STRENGH` and `WEAKNESS` because I may check them afterwards (*in fact, my real dataset has much more questions than these, so I wouldn't like to have to subset every single multiple-option column before analysing*)
- 2. Ultimately, I'm trying to answer the following question **What's the proportion of types of `STRATEGY` in relation to `School Type A` , `School Type B` , etc** ?

```
## I don't think the code is right for #2 : 

df1 %>% 
  count(STRATEGY, SCHOOL) %>% 
  group_by(SCHOOL)  %>% 
  mutate(prop = round((prop.table(n) * 100), digits = 2),
         sd = round(sd(prop.table(n)), digits = 2))

## I guess it (ALMOST) works if I convert STRATEGY separatedly:

# sep:

df1 <-  df %>% 
  pivot_longer(c(STRATEGY)) %>%
  separate_rows(value, sep = ",") %>%
  # group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider() %>%
  select(-row) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(-ID), na_if,"")  %>% 
  select(ID, SCHOOL, STRATEGY)


# count 
## prob: It feels like it's grouping by STRATEGY, not by SCHOOL

df1 %>% 
count(STRATEGY, SCHOOL) %>% 
  group_by(SCHOOL)  %>% 
  mutate(prop = round((prop.table(n) * 100), digits = 2),
         sd = round(sd(prop.table(n)), digits = 2))

# output:

> head(out)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   SCHOOL [4]
  STRATEGY              SCHOOL            n  prop    sd
  <chr>                 <chr>         <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1 " Facebook)"          School type A     3 12     0.04
2 " Facebook)"          School type B     2  9.09  0.03
3 " Facebook)"          School type C     2  9.09  0.03
4 " Facebook)"          School type D     3 16.7   0.04
5 " listening to music" School type A     1  4     0.04
6 " listening to music" School type B     1  4.55  0.03
```

- data:

```
dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c("PERSON_1", "PERSON_2", "PERSON_3", "PERSON_4", 
"PERSON_5", "PERSON_6", "PERSON_7", "PERSON_8", "PERSON_9", "PERSON_10", 
"PERSON_10", "PERSON_12", "PERSON_13", "PERSON_14", "PERSON_15", 
"PERSON_16", "PERSON_17", "PERSON_18", "PERSON_19", "PERSON_20", 
"PERSON_21", "PERSON_22", "PERSON_23", "PERSON_24", "PERSON_25"
), ORIGIN = c("RJ", "SP", "AM", "BA", "GO", "MT", "RR", "RO", 
"MS", "SC", "CE", "ES", "TO", "MG", "PR", "AC", "PA", "MA", "PI", 
"DF", "SE", "PB", "RN", "RS", "AP"), SCHOOL = c("School type C", 
"School type C", "School type D", "School type A", "School type B", 
"School type A", "School type A", "School type A", "School type C", 
"School type C", "School type B", "School type C", "School type D", 
"School type B", "School type A", "School type A", "School type B", 
"School type D", "School type D", "School type C", "School type A", 
"School type C", "School type A", "School type B", "School type B"
), STRATEGY = c("listening to podcasts, social media (Instagram, Twitter, Facebook), Watching youtube videos", 
"reading books, listening to music, watching Netflix", "social media (Instagram, Twitter, Facebook), Watching youtube videos", 
"reading books, social media (Instagram, Twitter, Facebook), Watching youtube videos, watching Netflix", 
"reading books, listening to music, reading blogs", "listening to music, reading blogs", 
"reading books, listening to music, listening to podcasts", "listening to podcasts, social media (Instagram, Twitter, Facebook)", 
"listening to podcasts", "listening to music, Watching youtube videos", 
"listening to music, listening to podcasts, social media (Instagram, Twitter, Facebook), Watching youtube videos, reading blogs, watching Netflix", 
"reading books, listening to music, listening to podcasts, reading blogs", 
"listening to podcasts, social media (Instagram, Twitter, Facebook)", 
"reading blogs, watching Netflix", "social media (Instagram, Twitter, Facebook)", 
"reading books, Watching youtube videos, reading blogs", "Watching youtube videos, reading blogs, watching Netflix", 
"reading books, listening to music, social media (Instagram, Twitter, Facebook), Watching youtube videos, watching Netflix", 
"reading books, listening to podcasts, reading blogs", "listening to music, listening to podcasts", 
"reading books, Watching youtube videos", "listening to podcasts, social media (Instagram, Twitter, Facebook), Watching youtube videos", 
"listening to music, listening to podcasts", "reading books, social media (Instagram, Twitter, Facebook)", 
"listening to music, listening to podcasts"), PREFERENCE = c("", 
"", "twitter", "", "youtube", "", "", "", "podcasts", "", "", 
"", "Podcasts", "Netflix", "TiK Tok", "blogs", "Netflix", "YOUTUBE", 
"BOOKS", "MUSIC", "books", "INSTA", "PODCASTS", "Facebook", "MUSIC"
), STRENGH = c("", "reading books in English, watching tv shows in English", 
"", "", "reading books in English, watching tv shows in English", 
"listening to music in English, reading books in English, listening to podcasts in English, watching movies in English, watching tv shows in English", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "watching tv shows in English, watching plays in English", 
"", "", "listening to music in English, reading books in English, listening to podcasts in English", 
"reading books in English, watching tv shows in English", "", 
"reading books in English, watching tv shows in English, watching plays in English", 
"watching plays in English", "reading books in English, listening to podcasts in English, watching tv shows in English", 
"", "listening to podcasts in English, watching tv shows in English", 
"listening to music in English", "listening to podcasts in English, watching movies in English, watching tv shows in English, watching plays in English"
), WEAKNESS = c("", "", "listening to podcasts in English, watching tv shows in English", 
"", "", "", "listening to podcasts in English, watching tv shows in English", 
"", "reading books in English, listening to podcasts in English, watching movies in English, watching tv shows in English, watching plays in English", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "listening to podcasts in English, watching plays in English", 
"reading books in English, listening to podcasts in English, watching movies in English, watching tv shows in English, watching plays in English", 
"listening to music in English, reading books in English", "", 
"listening to podcasts in English, watching tv shows in English"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -25L))
```

Comment: You don't have NAs or `""` in `STRATEGY`, but you are creating a single column of values from `STRATEGY`, `STRENGTH`, and `WEAKNESS`, where those columns have blanks (`""`), which is converted to `NA` with `na_if`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the description, we may need to split to longer format with `separate_longer_delim` and then do the `count` and `proportion` after grouping by 'SCHOOL'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   select(SCHOOL, STRATEGY) %>% 
   separate_longer_delim(STRATEGY, delim = regex(",\\s*")) %>% 
   count(SCHOOL, STRATEGY) %>%
   group_by(SCHOOL) %>%
   mutate(Prop = proportions(n)) %>% 
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 36 × 4
   SCHOOL        STRATEGY                    n   Prop
   <chr>         <chr>                   <int>  <dbl>
 1 School type A Facebook)                   3 0.12  
 2 School type A Twitter                     3 0.12  
 3 School type A Watching youtube videos     3 0.12  
 4 School type A listening to music          3 0.12  
 5 School type A listening to podcasts       3 0.12  
 6 School type A reading blogs               2 0.08  
 7 School type A reading books               4 0.16  
 8 School type A social media (Instagram     3 0.12  
 9 School type A watching Netflix            1 0.04  
10 School type B Facebook)                   2 0.0909
# … with 26 more rows
```